# Impelementing a stack using a 2 queues, and a queue using 2 stacks

Tags: algorithms, time-complexity, stacks

I have thought about it for a while, and I'm not really sure what is the best way to:

> 1.Implement a stack using 2 queues.
>
> 2.Implement a queue using 2 stacks.

I have only though about something trivial that takes O(n) time for dequeue and enqueue, and O(n) time for push and pop.

Can I do better than that?
Are there more efficient ways to do 1 and 2?